# Trouble understanding how to use .on properly

Tags: jquery

Probably a silly question, but still new to JQuery.

I have a div acting as a button to load in content via .load, problem is anything I load in JS will not work on it.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="a" id="aa">Button #1</div>
</br>
</br>
<div id="loada"></div>
</br>
</br>
<div id="loadb"></div>
```

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#aa').click(function(){
    $('#loada').load('load.htm #bb');
});
  $('#bb').click(function(){
    $('#loadn').load('load.htm #cc');
});
```

});

**Load HTM:**

```
<div class="b" id="bb">Button #2</div>
<div class="c" id="cc">Content #1</div>
```

I understand that you need to use .on for already loaded JS to work on dynamically created HTML, however I can't seem to get it right.

Anyone able to help?

Edit: What is wrong with the below?

```
$('#bb').on('click', '#bb', function(event){
  $('#loadb').load('load.htm #cc');
});
```

Comment: Use `$(document).on('event', 'selector', function)` like `$(document).on('click', '#aaa', function() {...})`

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#selector").on("click", function(event){
});
```

delegated-events approach attaches an event handler to only one elemen

```
 $("#selector").on("click", "selector", function(event){

    });
```

Comment: Could you explain this further for me?

Comment: @user2206632 A delegated-events approach attaches an event handler to only one element, the bb, and the event only needs to bubble up one level.See here http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: Check my edit at the bottom of the OP, what have I done wrong there?

Comment: cc is the ID of the div I'm trying to load via button 2. aa loads bb, then bb loads cc.

Comment: ok.is it not working fpr u

Comment: bb and cc are dynamically creating

Comment: Yep, but I can't get bb to work.

Comment: Ugh, I can't get it to work >.< Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

you can try make click on callback function of load like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#aa').click(function(){
    $('#loada').load('load.htm #bb',function(){
        $('#bb').click(function(){
            $('#loadb').load('load.htm #cc');
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('#aa').on("click",function(){
        $('#loada').load('load.htm #bb');
           $('#bb').on("click",function(){
                   $('#loadn').load('load.htm #cc');
                 });
          });
    });

if you are using jQuery 1.9 use "on" , if using older version use "live". [live is deprecated remember.]
```

Comment: Isn't this the same code the OP has? The one that does not work?

Comment: Ok, it is different now, but it still bears the same problem. The event handler is still bound before the element exists.